# What does the yellow exclamation point on actions mean?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Often as I interact with the world, I often see an exclamation point on certain actions.

[image]
[image]

It can appear on door "Open" and "Close" actions, "Kill" actions when grabbing enemies, and others.

**What could it possibly mean?**

As far as I can tell, there aren't any quest objectives related to doing that action so it seems to be for something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The yellow exclamation point on particular actions indicates that the action is risky and/or illegal and may attract the attention of the police or guards sharing an association if they spot you while performing the action.

Comment: Note that the game is currently very buggy. There are times I performed "risky" actions in plain view without anyone saying anything, and times I performed "safe" actions, causing everyone to attack me.